# How to generate working SSL certificates for client authentication on home server?

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, client-certificates

After several tries based on various tutorials, I've finally determined that my Apache configuration is working, but browsers will not accept my generated client certificate. Specifically, neither Windows nor OSX seem to recognize it as a client certificate; it imports successfully, but is not included in the list of certificates when prompted.  Chrome for example just gives the cryptic 'ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERR' and says the server sent an invalid response.

I'll omit the steps for setting up base SSL/HTTPS.  The following is what I've done to add client auth:

Server Cfg:

```
cd /var/www-auth/ca
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
 // Note: CN to "myth", matching the name of the server on my LAN.
Edit Apache's default-ssl.conf to set SSLACACertificateFile to /var/www-auth/ca/ca.crt and SSLVerifyClient require
```

Client Cert Generation:

```
openssl genrsa -out client.key 4096
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt
cat client.crt client.key > client.pem
```

Command-line test that works:

> curl --insecure --cert-type pem --cert client.pem https://myth

Importing the same '.pem' file in the browser (.crt or .pem) gives no obvious errors, but the browser will not send the certificate. On a system with other client certs installed, the prompt lists my other certs, but omits this new one.

What am I doing wrong?